# Integrate OpenCV with Android Project

Tags: opencv, android

I'm trying to integrate OpenCV SDK with my Android Studio project but I don't have any idea on how to do so. I'm fairly new to android and know only the basics. All the solutions I can find are at least 5 or 6 years old so can someone please give me an updated solution. Thank you.

(I basically need the steps to integrate OpenCV with my project)

Comment: Which implementation of OpenCV are you using? Python, C++, Java? Keep in mind that Android development is typically made in Java. If your OpenCV project is not implemented in Java, there could be some "problems". Maybe "problems" is not the right word, but the steps needed to integrate both systems are definitely more and more difficult.

Comment: I'm using Java in Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of explanations and tutorials at https://opencv.org/android/ -- both for the people new to Android and people new to OpenCV. Please, read the pages, do the tutorials, then ask more specific questions here.